# Sample a random number following a distribution between two values

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, gaussian, sampling

I would like to create a gaussian curve between two values (which is the end point of two different calculations). I am aware that i require a bit more background info, but i wish to play with the result. So let us assume what is not known, the values in question may be 1.9 and 2.1.
[image]

My goals is to to draw a number randomly between those two, and be more biased to the mean than to the one or the other extreme as a start point for the next calculation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE I:**

for clarity,

both blue and black lines start at some origin, the calculation differs and the values at the end points are different. From only those two values, any amount of ppoints can be set up. n can be between 2 and 100 - it does not matter. The point is, to create a distribution like indicated by the bell shaped curve.

Following Severin Pappadeux's excellent suggestion, we now have defined n, which now leaves us only to define the distribution.

[image]

```
n=10

IH=1.9:0.01:2.1
v = 1.9 + ((2.1-1.9)/n) * IH(n)

bar(IH)
hold on
bar(n,v,'k')
```

**UPDATE II:**
**RESULTS!**

As you can see, the curve multiplied into two curves, with each having a distribution of possible outcomes from which another calculation is started. The purpose was to be close to a setpoint. Im almost done, so

Big Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can't define a Gaussian using two values as endpoints, because the range of a Gaussian is infinite.  You'd need to specify what proportion of it you want to have fall between the two values.  Also, it's not at all clear to me what your picture is supposed to represent.

Comment: Thank you, I clarified the problem statement a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might use Irwin-Hall from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Basically,

```
min(IH(n)) = 0
max(IH(n)) = n
peak(IH(n)) = n/2
```

Scaling to your [1.9...2.1] range

v = 1.9 + ((2.1-1.9)/n) * IH(n)

It is bounded, very easy to sample, and at large `n` it is pretty much gaussian. You could vary `n` to get narrow or wide peak

Sampling, in some C pseudocode

```
double IH(int n) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
         s += uniform_random_number();

    return s;
}
```

UPDATE

translated to Octave

```
function rv = IH(n)
  rv = 0.0;
  for i = 1:n
    x  = rand;
    rv = rv + x;
  end
endfunction
```

So sampling would be along the line (say, one million events, IH with 8 d.o.f)

```
n = 8
for k = 1:1000000
  v = 1.9 + ((2.1-1.9)/n) * IH(n);
  % process v
end
```

Another update, added function QG, which generates desired random vector

```
function [x] = QG (n, k)
  for i = 1:k
    x(i) = 1.9 + ((2.1-1.9)/n)*IH(n);
  end
endfunction
```

Try to fill histrogram, along the lines

```
y = QG(8, 10000);
h = histogram(y);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am struggling with your pseudocode though, could you be a little more matlab specific, I am not familiar with C.

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly translated to Octave (which is a Matlab clone), try it

Comment: this is brilliantly concise and does exactly what its supposed to do. So many kind thanks! what does IH and QG stand for? 

On a different note, you seem to be pretty proficient in this area. Could you elaborate a bit more about what you did in technical terms? Monte carlo? bootstrapping? resampling?

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly good to hear. IH stands for Irwin-Hall, because it returns value sampled according to the Irwin-Hall distrubution with `n` degress of freedom. QG stands for quasi-Gaussian, i.e. distribution with some core which looks gaussian, but is bounded and thus has different tails.

Comment: I will think I will give it one more day to think about possible questions to ask and include in the solution and then consider it solved :). How would you describe the solution in different, more techy words (except IH and QG which you already mentioned)?

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly  This is Monte Carlo sampling of the proposed distribution. Let's review the requirements. First, it should be gaussian. Second, it should fit within some range. Together it is impossible, because Gaussian is unbounded, tails go to +-infinity. But if you relax requirements and ask for something bounded but with gaussian "core", that could be done. I-H distribution fits the bill. It is based upon Central Limit Theorem which states, that average (which is sum divided by `n`) of several independent random variables would be approximately gaussian. To be continued...

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly And if we take those independent random variables in the simplest form - uniform random numbers in [0...1) interval - we get exactly I-H distribution. And by definition it is bounded. If you have IH with `n` samples, then all uniform random number might be `0`, so minimum is always `0`. Or all of the might be `1`, so maximum of IH(n) would be `n*1=n`. So "core" is approximately gaussian, and larger `n` makes it more gaussian. There are always bounds. So the only thing left is to shift IH(n) from [0...n] interval into desired [1.9-2.1], and fill outgoing vector.

Comment: is there a way how i could say I sample with 95% confidence from this interval? I see that I can play with n and k a lot but would like to be a bit more specific without having to pull a number 8 times out of 1 000 000 iterations.

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly Sure. You have original interval [1.9...2.1], so the probability to be sampled from this interval is 1, no events below 1.9 or above 2.1. So you need to compute distribution parameter `n` so that within some interval [a...b], where `a > 1.9` and `b < 2.1`, probability to get an event is 0.95. In the link to Irwin-Hall distribution there is expression for CDF(x, n), so with shift and for given `n` you just compute how much of CDF is below 0.025. If you can't figure it out, kick me tomorrow, I'll take a look at it over weekend

Comment: I cant figure it out, please elaborate. Currently I am using n=3 degrees of freedom and k=100 sampled points for my distribution within the interval. Id like to be able to claim that the samples I draw are to 95% certainty good values, and 2.5% could be even higher and 2.5 could be lower. I understand that the CDF looks easy to implement, but cant wrap my head around it.